# Nested methods to insert to database in C# is not inserting all the data

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, sql-insert

I have a service using 3 methods (each one calling another one) to insert data to 3 tables in sql azure. The first two methods insert the data correctly but the third one (the relationship of the other two) which recieves the indexes of the first two tables doesn't. The methods are something like:

```
public int InsertTableOne([FromBody]Object obj)
{
    int IdTableOne = 0;
    tring connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyString"];
            string queryString = "INSERT INTO TableOne (Name,Phone OUTPUT INSERTED.IdTableOne VALUES (@Name,@Phone) ";
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                con.Open();
                using (SqlTransaction tran = connection.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(queryString, con, tran))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", obj.Name);
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone",obj.Phone);
                            IdTableOne = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
                            InsertTableTwo(obj,IdTableOne)
                            tran.Commit();
                        }
                        catch()...
                        finally
                        {
                            con.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
}

public int InsertTableTwo([FromBody] ob obj,List<listOfElements> listofThings,int IdTableOne)
{
    int IdTableTwo = 0;
            string queryString = "INSERT INTO TableTwo (Car,Color) OUTPUT INSERTED.IdTableTwo VALUES(@Car,@Color)";

            string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyString"];
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(queryString, con))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Car","" );
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Color", "");

                        foreach (listOfElements thing in (listofThings))
                        {
                            command.Parameters["@Car"].Value = GetCar(thing.Car);//Methodo to get the car, works fine
                            command.Parameters["@Color"].Value = thing.Color;
                            IdTableTwo = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
                            InsertTableThree(IdTableOne, IdTableTwo);
                        }
                    }
                    catch()...
                }
            }
            return IdTableTwo;
}  

public int InsertTableThree(int IdTableOne,int IdTableTwo)
{
            string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyString"];
            string queryString = "INSERT INTO TableThree (IdTableOne,IdTableTwo) VALUES(@IdTableOne,@IdTableTwo)";
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                //connection.Open();
                using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(queryString, con))
                {
                    try
                    {
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdTableOne", IdTableOne);
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdTableTwo", IdTableTwo);
                            command.Parameters.Clear();

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
            return IdTableOne;
}
```

At the end, the first two tables receive the data but the last one remains empty without the indexes. There's no crash with the database, the transaction or the code. The only problem is that last table data.  Also when I debug it, the values of the indexes are correct at the time they're supposed to be inserted.

Comment: In the third method add "command.ExecuteNonQuery();"

Comment: You add the Parameters then you Clear - in your InsertTableThree method? why? and you can achieve your InsertTableThree method by using Trigger

Comment: @traxx02 I thought since I'm in a foreach loop that I needed to clear the parameters, but that was before I modify it and run the foreach after setting the parameters. You're right about the trigger, that would be my next step. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just preparing the command in last method but not executing it. Here is the modified version of third method.

```
public int InsertTableThree(int IdTableOne,int IdTableTwo)
    {
                string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyString"];
                string queryString = "INSERT INTO TableThree (IdTableOne,IdTableTwo) VALUES(@IdTableOne,@IdTableTwo)";
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    //connection.Open();
                    using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(queryString, con))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdTableOne", IdTableOne);
                                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdTableTwo", IdTableTwo);
                                comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                        }
                    }
                }
                return IdTableOne;
    }
```